# How can I alter my solution to work on TFS Build that works locally, can't find .dll in search path

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I've got a solution that builds locally on my developer box, and I've tried it using remote desktop on my TFS build server, which is server, controller, and agent. What is baffling is that when I queue a build, it fails, with this message in the log file.

> Considered "..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll", but it didn't exist.

Part of what is so confusing is that If I navigate to that location, I can see the file that I need.

In further testing, I went to the build source folder and loaded the solution there. It shows that it can't located the reference. If I just remove the reference, and re add the exact reference again, it builds.

If you have a better title or want further clarification just ask or make suggestions.

Comment: Are you looking at the relative path from the Project raising the error? Are there enough or too many ..\ that could be causing the issue.

Comment: @DaveShaw I'm not sure about the relative pathing, I'm not sure where it is executing. However, I know the path it is using is generated from the reference path. TFS or MSBuild made that path, so it creating a bad path are included in the question.

Comment: OK, have you tried a build with logging set to diagnostic? These logs can be a pain to read due to the shear volume of data they spit out, but you might be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: @DaveShaw That brings up a possibly relevant detail. This project is being built using the default tfs 2013 template, which is very different from the 2012 template. It doesn't have a verbosity argument.